# Why does grabbing mishandle my shape?

Tags: vertices, transforms

I am currently making Blender Guru's Beginner Tutorial where he creates a Donut. I want to move the glaze more towards the base of the donut but it doesn't work (see images).

Hopefully, you can help me out and tell me what I did wrong.

Thanks in advance,
Tobi[image: problem]

[image]

Comment: because you must have enabled the snap to face option, it makes the whole selection snap to the face of the other object

Comment: Hello and welcome. While there are many possibilities, @moonboots may already have seen something like it before and got it right. I would though recommend to include the user interface of the viewport in screenshots, as there are many icons, especially at the top of the viewport, that *can* give clues about a setting and the situation. This would allowing others to easier conclude why something might not work. You can always edit your question and add more information for others to have it easier figuring out what went wrong.